# Task Scheduler runs script fine but doesn't append to text file

Tags: python, file, append, task, scheduler

So I have a simple program that appends a value to a text file.  When I manually run it, it appends the value just fine.  When I schedule it to automatically run with Task scheduler, the program runs but doesn't append to the file.  Any ideas?

```
totalvalue = 23
with open("text.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("\n")
    myfile.write(str(totalvalue))
    myfile.write("\n")
myfile.close()
```

Comment: I used xstarter and that seems to be working